# Generating call graph for assembly instructions

Tags: assembly, call-graph

I'm writing a tool and I need to generate the callgraph for assembly instructions. But I do not know how to exactly generate call graph from assembly instruction. Do you have any idea?
To clarify, I run a binary sample in sandbox environment and extract its trace in assembly language. So now I want to generate call graph for that?

Comment: Since you're tracing the program you can record CALL and RET instructions, where they are and where they jump to, so you can easily build a call graph from that. (That ingores the fact you can effectively make calls and returns using other instructions, but other than tail chaining JMPs, that's pretty much the realm of obfuscated code.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to have a call graph similar to what IDA will generate which contains Local functions(implemented by the program designer) and External functions(system and library calls). So how can I distinguish which function will be called?

Comment: IDA analyzes the program statically using heuristics. You're apparently actually running the program in sandbox and tracing it. Because you're tracing it you know exactly what functions are actually being called. I don't see the problem here. Local functions have addresses within the executable being traced, external ones don't.